# This is my jQuery file.. I want to remove pagination and want to display every record in page

Tags: jquery, datatables

My jQuery file. How to edit it in order to remove pagination?
................................................................

```
$('#sample_2').dataTable({
                // "aLengthMenu": [
                //     [5, 15, 20, -1],
                //     [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                // ],
                // set the initial value
                // "iDisplayLength": 5,
                //"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "oLanguage": {
                   // "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ per page",
                   "bPaginate": false,
                    "oPaginate": false,
                     "paging":   false,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info":     false
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': [0]
                    }
                ]
            });

            jQuery('#sample_2 .group-checkable').change(function () {
                var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
                var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
                jQuery(set).each(function () {
                    if (checked) {
                        $(this).attr("checked", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("checked", false);
                    }
                });
                jQuery.uniform.update(set);
            });

            jQuery('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-small"); // modify table search input
            //jQuery('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("form-control input-xsmall"); // modify table per page dropdown
           // jQuery('#sample_2_wrapper .dataTables_length select').select2(); // initialize select2 dropdown
```

.......................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery datatables, to disable its pagination you need to use

`"bPaginate": false`. So just do

```
$('#sample_2').dataTable({
               "bPaginate": false,
});
```

You have included it at wrong place in your code inside `"oLanguage"`.

[See the documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features).

Comment: It doesn't work and script also shows waring that datatable can not be reinitialized..

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454190/cannot-reinitialise-jquery-datatable

Comment: Actually this is my first jQuery script so I have no idea how to edit formatted code:/

Comment: To remove pagination from datatables you need to do `"bPaginate": false,`. That's it. If other parts in your script are correct then this should work fine. Remove all options from dataTable and see if it works with just `$('#sample_2').dataTable({"bPaginate": false,
});`

Comment: It works but searchbox is disappear and I want to display it.. So what to do ??

Comment: For search `"oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Filter Data" },`. See this: http://plnkr.co/edit/guLsx1MLWD1SGPLbF5Xo?p=preview Also read some jQuery and do a Google search before you ask questions, and yes read the documentation of dataTable.